# How to remove duplicate words in a cell only if longer than a certain number of characters?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I need to remove a duplicate text in a cell but only if it is longer than 4 characters.

I have this formula that only works for any types of duplicate words:

```
=join(" ",unique(transpose(split(A1,", "))))
```

In this case, if a cell contains:

```
W3-X500 Samsung Galaxy W3-X500 5 inches and 5 different colors
```

It returns me:

```
W3-X500 Samsung Galaxy 5 inches and different colors
```

I will lose the second `5` character that instead I need.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" ", 
 UNIQUE(IF(LEN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1, ", "))), 
        IF(LEN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1, ", ")))>4, 
               TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1, ", ")), 
        IF(LEN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1, ", ")))<=4, 
               TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1, ", "))&
 "ᅇ"&CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(SIGN(ROW($A:$A))*1041, 1071))&
      CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(SIGN(ROW($A:$A))*1041, 1071))&
      CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(SIGN(ROW($A:$A))*1041, 1071))&
      CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(SIGN(ROW($A:$A))*1041, 1071))&
      CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(SIGN(ROW($A:$A))*1041, 1071))&"ᅇ", )), )))), 
 "\ᅇ([Б-Я]+)\ᅇ", "")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Complex problem for what might seem to be a simple thing, Max. The following formula will remove duplicates if they appear to be a model number (i.e., they begin with a capital letter and are not recognized as a mathematical number):

**`=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF((VLOOKUP(transpose(split(A1," ")),{transpose(split(A1," ")),QUERY({ROW(A1:A100)},"Select * Limit "&COUNTA(transpose(split(A1," "))))},2,FALSE)=QUERY({ROW(A1:A100)},"Select * Limit "&COUNTA(transpose(split(A1," ")))))*(LEFT(transpose(split(A1," ")),1)=UPPER(LEFT(transpose(split(A1," ")),1)))+(ISNUMBER(transpose(split(A1," "))))>0,transpose(split(A1," ")),"")))`**

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(JOIN(" ", UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1, ", ")&
 IF(LEN(SPLIT(A1, ", "))<=4, REPT("ᅇ", 
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&COUNTA(SPLIT(A1, ", ")))))), "")))), "ᅇ", ""))
```

[image]